# How come after generating a screenshot at the same coordinates every time, files may sometimes have different hash signatures?

Tags: windows, macros, web, screenshot, hashing

I am having a hard time figuring out the reason to this. I have a macro running that is screen capturing using snipping tool at the same exact coordinates every single time within a web site (a table) in FireFox.

The problem is sometimes it generates screen captures with different hashes (MD5, CRC, all consistent etc). Sometimes the hashes are equal. It's like a box of chocolates. You never know what you're going to get. The content should not vary if the coordinates are the same every time, and the content being captured is the same.

Can anyone explain as to why this is happening? I am trying to make the screenshot theoretically 99% consistent and generate the same MD5 hash unless content within the table had changed.

Technical details:

- Windows Snipping Tool on Windows 10 latest build
- .PNG output screen shot
- Same coordinates
- Same webpage
- Different hashes occasionally, same hashes occasionally

Comment: Try it in full screen mode and see what happens

Comment: Would you mind elaborating some more? FireFox is already in full screen mode with the website ready.

Comment: oh. It's already in full screen mode?  I thought maybe some of the browses ui elements might be causing the issue

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Nope, I have not tried a different browser yet. I might try Internet Explorer, but that should not really affect the screen cap, don't you think?

Comment: it isn't working now, you have nothing to lose. It could very well be Firefox's rendering engine is inconsistent

Comment: I was thinking it could be related. I will try that out and see how it works. Thank you for the tip.

Any other ideas / comments would be appreciated!

Comment: A PNG file isn’t the exact representation of your screenshot. It is a compressed data file and it is not lossless. What is in the PNG is not technically what is exactly on your screen and it is not surprising the contents vary. If even 1 bit is off, your hash is completely different but the image looks exactly the same.

Comment: @Appleoddity That was the answer I was afraid of. So, to clarify, I should not use PNGs and expect them to be the same content because they are not exact copies and not lossless when they are generated.